# Why is my form 'submitting' when it shouldn't?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, submit

This is a follow-up to an earlier question.

I have an HTML page with a number of buttons, one of which asks the user for confirmation.  The code now correctly pauses updates of the page (thank you, Nils!) and puts the two options - Cancel and Confirm - on the screen.  Temporary debugging calls show that the two functions, `cancel.onclick` and `confirm.onclick` are running correctly, depending on which button is clicked.

However, although the `document.getElementById("systemReset").submit();` call is ONLY in the Confirm routine, it fires whichever button I click!

I have included the full page because I know how frustrating it can be when trying to answer a question to have only a portion of the code!  Search for the !-- [02] -- markers for the relevant sections.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--  Version 9.26  -->
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10">
    <style type="text/css">
      .button{padding:5px; font-size:14px; width:90px; border-radius:4px; margin-right:10px;}
      .long{width:179px;}
      .controls{margin-left:30px; margin-right:30px; margin-top:20px; width:160px;}
      h2{margin:0px; color:blue; font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;}
      h4{font-size:14px; font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; margin:10px; margin-top:0px; padding:6px; border:2px; color:black; text-align:center;}
      h4.b{border-style:inset;}
      span.caption{font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size:14px; margin-top:0px; margin-right:5px; padding:5px; color:black;}
      span.val{padding:3px; width:60px; border-style:inset; background-color:white; font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold;}
      /* The Modal (background) */
      .modal {
        display: none; /* Hidden by default */
        position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
        z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
        padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 725px;
        height: 435px;
        overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
        background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
      }
      .modal-content {background-color: #fefefe; font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
        margin: auto; padding: 20px; border: 3px solid #888; width: 80%;}
      .cancel {color: red; font-size:36px; font-weight: bold; cursor: pointer; padding: 10px; float: right;}
      .confirm {color: green; font-size:36px; font-weight: bold; cursor: pointer; padding: 10px; float: right;}
    </style>
  <title>CH Controller</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="background-color:black;width:700px;padding:3px;">
      <div style="background-color:LemonChiffon; padding:5px;">
        <h2>Hot Water</h2>
      </div>
      <form method="POST"target="_self">
        <div style="background-color:LemonChiffon; color:white; padding:10px;">
          <input class="button" type="submit" name="btn_HW_Mode" value="@@btn_HW_Mode@@">
          <input class="button" type="submit" name="btn_HWboth" value="ON (Both)">
          <input class="button" type="submit" name="btn_HWdown" value="ON (Down)">
          <input style="width:60px;" class="button" type="submit" name="btn_HWoff" value="OFF">
          <h4 class="b" style="float:right; background-color:@@HW_ModeBg@@; color:black; width:90px;">@@HW_Mode@@</h4>
          <h4 class="b" style="float:right; background-color:@@HW_StsBg@@; color:@@HW_StsFg@@; width:40px;">@@HW_Sts@@</h4>
        </div>
        <div style="background-color:LemonChiffon;color:white;padding:10px;">
          <input class="button long" type="submit" name="btn_HW5onBoth" value="5 Mins On (Both)">
          <input class="button long" type="submit" name="btn_HW5onDown" value="5 Mins On (Down)">
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div style="background-color:black; width:700px; padding:3px;">
      <div style="background-color:MistyRose; padding:5px;">
        <h2>Underfloor Heating</h2>
      </div>
      <form method="POST" target="_self">
        <div style="background-color:MistyRose; color:white; padding:10px;">
          <input class="button" type="submit" name="btn_CH_Mode" value="@@btn_CH_Mode@@">
          <input class="button" type="submit" name="btn_CHon" value="UFH ON">
          <input style="width:60px;" class="button" type="submit" name="btn_CHoff" value="OFF">
          <h4 class="b" style="float:right; background-color:@@CH_ModeBg@@; color:black; width:90px;">@@CH_Mode@@</h4>
          <h4 class="b" style="float:right; background-color:@@CH_StsBg@@; color:white; width:40px;">@@CH_Sts@@</h4>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div style="background-color:black; width:700px; padding:3px;">
      <div style="background-color:LightCyan; padding:5px;">
        <table style="width:100%";>
          <tr>
            <td style="width:150px";> <!-- [01] -->
              <h2>System Status</h2> <!-- [01] -->
            </td>
            <td style="width:50px";> <!-- [01] -->
              (v@@ver@@) <!-- [01] -->
            </td>
            <td style="width:150px;"> <!-- [02] -->
              <button style="color:white; background-color:#f44336; width:120px; float:right;" id="btnReset" onclick="stopRefresh()">Reset System!</button>
              <div id="confirmation" class="modal">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <p>Continuing with this action will reset the main processor.</p>
                  <p>Are you quite sure you wish to do this?
                  <span id="cancel" class="cancel">&#9746;</span>
                  <span id="confirm" class="confirm">&#9745;</span></p>
                </div>
                <form id="systemReset" method="POST" target="_self">
                  <input type="hidden" id="rS" name="btn_Reset">
                </form>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <h2 style="float:right;">@@Time@@</h2>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div style="background-color:LightCyan; color:white; padding:10px">
        <span class="caption" style="color:black;">Primary Pump:</span>
        <span class="val" style="background-color:@@Pri_StsBg@@; color:white;">@@Pri_Sts@@</span>
        <span class="caption" style="color:black;">Boiler:</span>
        <span class="val" style="background-color:@@Blr_StsBg@@; color:white;">@@Blr_Sts@@</span>
        <span class="caption" style="color:black;">HW Temp:</span>
        <span class="val" style="background-color:@@HWtempBg@@; color:black;">@@HWtemp@@&deg;</span>
        <span class="caption" style="color:black;">UFH Temp:</span>
        <span class="val" style="background-color:@@CHtempBg@@; color:black;">@@CHtemp@@&deg;</span>
        <span class="caption" style="color:black;">Panel Temp:</span>
        <span class="val" style="background-color:@@PnltempBg@@; color:black;">@@Pnltemp@@&deg;</span>
        <table style="width:100%"; border:none; padding:10px;>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <form method="POST" target="_self">
                <input class="button controls" type="submit" name="btn_Pri_Pump" value="Toggle Primary Pump">
              </form>  
            </td>
            <td>
              <form method="POST" target="_self">
                <input class="button controls" type="submit" name="btn_Boiler" value="Toggle Boiler">
              </form>
            </td>
            <td>
              <form action="/temps" method="POST" target="_self">
                <input class="button controls" type="submit" name="btn_Show_Temps" value="Show All Temperatures">
              </form>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      var modal = document.getElementById("confirmation");
      var btn = document.getElementById("btnReset");
      var cancel = document.getElementsByClassName("cancel")[0];
      var confirm = document.getElementsByClassName("confirm")[0];
  
      btn.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "block";
        stopRefresh();
      }
  
      cancel.onclick = function() {
        window.alert("In cancel.onclick function");
        modal.style.display = "none";
        startRefresh();
      }
      
      confirm.onclick = function() {
        window.alert("In confirm.onclick function");
        modal.style.display = "none";
        startRefresh();
        document.getElementById("systemReset").submit();
      }
  
      const stopRefresh = () => {
        window.stop(); // Use this to stop the refresh: when modal opens
      }
      const startRefresh = () => {
        document.location.reload(); // Resume the refresh: when modal closes
      }
    </script>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because you `onclick` handlers don't disable the `onsubmit` handler on the form which automatically submits. Use `type="button"` instead of `type="submit"`

Comment: I understand what you are saying, Konrad, but I don't see anywhere that I am using ```type=submit```.    Where are you suggesting that I make this change?